# Caracteres especiales FPDF

Tags: fpdf

Que tal el problema es que no me respeta los caracteres con coma

La parte que quiero que interprete los caracteres especiales es en las variables por ejemplo en $puesto

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',3);
$pdf->SetXY(5, 29);
$pdf->Cell(28,5,'Puesto: '. $puesto,1,1,'L');
```

Ya intente con `utf-8_decode()`
Y también con :

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-5'
```

Sin exito
Así se mira;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$sql="SELECT  t1.nombre,  t1.apellido_paterno, t1.apellido_materno, t1.area, t2.puesto ,t1.noimss, t1.llam_emergencia FROM personal t1 left join puestos t2 on t1.puesto=t2.id where t1.idPersonal='".$idpersonall."'";
$exec =mysqli_query($condb,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($exec);

$querydpt="SELECT * FROM areas";
$ejecuta=mysqli_query($condb,$querydpt);
$arr=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecuta);
$area=$arr['departamento'];

$nombre=$row['nombre'];
$apellidoP=$row['apellido_paterno'];
$apellidoM=$row['apellido_materno'];
$llam_eme=$row['llam_emergencia'];
$puesto=$row['puesto'];
$noimss=$row['noimss'];

$pdf = new FPDF('L', 'mm', array(55,85));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetMargins(15, 12 , 15);
```

Comment: ¿De dónde vienen esos datos: base de datos, archivo de texto, etc...? Si puedes muestra el código con el que los obtienes.

Comment: Si, de la base de datos, acabo de editar la pregunta para agregar el query y como mando a llamas el dato

Comment: Casi seguro que los datos vienen mal de la BD porque no estableciste el charset adecuado. Haz esto antes de ejecutar las consultas: **`$condb->set_charset("utf8");`** Con eso debería resolverse el problema, a no ser que los datos estén mal en la base de datos, lo cual deberías revisar si sigue saliendo mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con esto

```
pdf->Cell(28,5,'Puesto: '. utf8_decode($puesto),1,1,'L');
```

saludos

Comment: No lo había intentado solo con la variable y pues funciono, gracias

Comment: Un placer, saludos